# Why is gcc giving "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"?

Tags: updates, gcc, format

I noticed my gcc seems to be broken (I'm using Ubuntu 18)

```
$ gcc --version
-bash: /usr/bin/gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I tried reinstalling it ...

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 249 not upgraded.
Need to get 5184 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://iad-2.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 [5184 B]
Fetched 5184 B in 0s (33.8 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 135285 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) over (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up gcc (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

but I still get the same error

```
$ gcc --version
-bash: /usr/bin/gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What else do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64 bit?  uname -a should tell you.  You might have a 32 bit 18.04 from an upgrade.